# Problems with connection between Pc and multiplexer Mitutoyo mux10f

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using a multiplexer to read from a height gage, both from Mitutoyo, the multiplexer is mux 10f and the manual says the commads that get the data to the pc, the problem is I don't understand it, image is below.
I tried a program in c# using
 `_serialport.Write("1");`
But doesn't work. Can someone help me please I'm not very good at programming :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf8vp.jpg

Comment: You need a CR : Try _serialport.WriteLine("1");

Comment: Sorry mate but you need to post more than only one line of your program. And a better description of what you expected the results to be and what actual results you got. We need to understand your problem better to be able to help you

Comment: The image says that you need to send a 1 followed by a " carriage return" this is what the CR means. Afterwards the device will transfer the data from Chanel 1 back to the PC. The CR in a string will look like this `"1\r"`

Comment: Yes ,that worked thanks. "1/r" it's what i needed